# Model Proliferation / Ability to set table name at runtime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

TL;DR - can I set table name at query time (not set_table_name - don't want it at the class level) and use arel-style finders w/o a proper representation of the model (foo.rb) in my codebase?

Long Version...

I've got two dozen tables in a warehouse with consistent schema across the tables:

```
date | some_foreign_key | total
```

Let's say the tables are named

```
activity_by_foo
activity_by_bar
activity_by_baz
```

If I were following AR part-and-parcel, I'd have three model class:

```
app/models/activity_by_foo.rb
app/models/activity_by_bar.rb
app/models/activity_by_baz.rb
```

And I can either include a module in each of these classes to handle common lookups or write a base class and explicitly call 'set_table_name' in each model allowing this to work:

```
class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.totals_for_period(start_date, end_date, id) 
     select(:total).where(:start_date => start_date, :end_date => end_date,  :some_foreign_key => id).sum(:total)
  end
end
```

However, I'd like to purge the activity_by_foo/bar/baz classes altogether and do something a bit more dynamically. Assuming I'm adding no additional behavior to the model, I'm literally just pulling out data for presentation, is it possible for me to still use arel-style finder syntax on a 'virtual' ActiveRecord class (in this case Activity) and somehow set the table name at query time based on other information available to me?